# Edit a crontab with Ansible

Tags: cron, ansible

I would like to use Ansible in order to edit a crontab as the following line :

`00 08 * * 1-5 /appli/script.ksh > /var/log/cronlog.log 2>&1`

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Yo might want to use the [cron](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/cron_module.html) module.

```
- cron:
    name: "Run script.ksh Mo-Fr at 8AM"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "8"
    weekday: "1-5"
    job: "/appli/script.ksh > /var/log/cronlog.log 2>&1"
```

Comment: Suggest not to specify the schedule in the job-name, because if we reschedule, one of two things will happen: If we forget to updated the name - it is now misleading, and if we DO rename the job - we now have two different jobs (old one and new one), and both are active.